# Sprite Kit iOS7 - Add Slider

Tags: uislider, sprite-kit

I thought you could add UIKit slider/or button to your sprite kit app.

But cannot figure out how to do this, the code to create a slider programatically is

```
if (self.view) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    //[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
    NSLog(@"View is alive - look for slider...");
} 
else {
    NSLog(@"No View!!");
}
```

The above does not work, the number of subviews of the view remains the same

I assume I have to add it as a child to my layer (SKNode), however the addChild method will not work with a UISlider. It needs to be an SKNode itself.

I am calling this within the scene class here

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
         // thought putting here would work 
         // but self.view is nil
    }

    return self;
}
```

Thanks to comment, I can get it to show - but I have to add in within the **viewController** class, like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [XBLMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];

if (self.view) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    //[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    NSLog(@"View is alive - look for slider...");
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
} else {
    NSLog(@"No View!!");
}
}
```

Is there not away to do it within the actual scene class ....

Thanks

Comment: when does this code run? Perhaps before the view is initialized? Check that view is non-nil.

Comment: It added right at the end of the usual inits, after I add other items to the screen.

Comment: No its not getting called... self above question edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some tinkering

My solution, thanks to @LearnCocos2D hint

My Scene Class needed this

```
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [self addSlider];
}
```

Then call your method to add the slider.... etc

Comment: Yes, that's the correct solution. Before that method runs there's simply no view associated with the scene.

Comment: can you add these UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController]; ?? I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. You just solved my technical issue. I tried and your solution works perfectly well.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same question and i wasn't satisfied with the `UISlider`. So created my own classes for Sprite Kit. There are buttons, joysticks, dpads and sliders. Maybe they help you improving your apps. In my games they work really good.

Be aware they are written in Swift.

**LESKSliderNode**

```
//
//  LESKSliderNode.swift
//  LESKClasses
//
//  Created by Cyrill Lippuner on 17.06.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 legelite. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit


class LESKSliderNode : SKNode
{
/**
Defines the Size of the LESKSliderNode.
*/
var size : CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
/**
Defines the AnchorPoint of the LESKSliderNode.
*/
//var anchorPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
/**
Defines frameInParent with the position of the superclass and the size of the LESKSliderNode.
*/
var frameInParent : CGRect
{
get {return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:self.position.x - 0.5 * self.size.width,y:self.position.y - 0.5 * self.size.height), size: self.size)}
set(newValue)
{
    super.position = newValue.origin
    self.size = newValue.size
    //self.value = self.valueRange.startIndex + ((newPositionX + range.endIndex) / (range.endIndex - range.startIndex)) * (self.valueRange.endIndex - self.valueRange.startIndex)
}
}

/**
Enables the LESKSliderNode to interactions.
*/
var isEnabled : Bool = true
/**
Displays whether a touch is in progress.
*/
var isActive : Bool = false
/**
Defines the space between the thumb and the edges of the scale.
*/
var overlayThumb : Bool = false {didSet{calculateNewThumbRange()}}
/**
Displays the value of thumb on the slider.
*/
var value : Float
{
get
{
    return  self.valueRange.startIndex + ((thumbSprite.position.x + self.thumbRange.endIndex) / (self.thumbRange.endIndex - self.thumbRange.startIndex)) * (self.valueRange.endIndex - self.valueRange.startIndex)
}
set(newValue)
{
    var val = newValue
    if newValue < self.valueRange.startIndex {val = self.valueRange.startIndex}
    else if newValue > self.valueRange.endIndex {val = self.valueRange.endIndex}
    let newPositionX = (val - self.valueRange.startIndex) * (self.thumbRange.endIndex - self.thumbRange.startIndex) / (self.valueRange.endIndex - self.valueRange.startIndex) - self.thumbRange.endIndex
    thumbSprite.position = CGPoint(x:newPositionX,y:thumbSprite.position.y)
    if self.thumbSpriteActive {self.thumbSpriteActive!.position = CGPoint(x:newPositionX,y:self.thumbSpriteActive!.position.y)}
}
}
/**
Defines the range of the values.
*/
var valueRange : Range<Float> = Range(start: 0.0, end: 1.0)
/**
The range of the thumb's position.
*/
var thumbRange : Range<Float> = Range(start: 0.0, end: 0.0)
/**
The range of the thumb's position.
*/
var thumbOffset : Float = 0.0
{
didSet
{
    self.thumbSprite.position = CGPoint(x:self.thumbSprite.position.x, y: self.thumbOffset)
    if self.thumbSpriteActive {self.thumbSpriteActive!.position = CGPoint(x:self.thumbSpriteActive!.position.x, y: self.thumbOffset)}
}
}


/**
ScaleSprite is the scale for the LESKSliderNode.
*/
let scaleSprite : SKSpriteNode
/**
ThumbSprite is the thumb for the LESKSliderNode.
*/
let thumbSprite : SKSpriteNode
/**
ScaleSpriteActive is the active scale for the LESKSliderNode.
*/
let scaleSpriteActive : SKSpriteNode?
/**
ThumbSpriteActive is the active thumb for the LESKSliderNode.
*/
let thumbSpriteActive : SKSpriteNode?

/**
Description of the LESKSliderNode
*/
override var description : String
{
get
{
    var string = "<LESKSliderNode> name: \(self.name) "
    string += "scaleSprite: [\(scaleSprite.description)] "
    string += "thumbSprites: [\(thumbSprite.description)] "
    string += "frame: \(self.frameInParent) rotation: \(self.zRotation) "
    string += "isEnabled: \(isEnabled) "
    if isEnabled {string += "isActive: \(isActive) overlayThumb: \(overlayThumb) range: \(valueRange) value: \(value)"}
    return string
}
}

/**
Typealiases
*/
typealias LESKSliderNodeCompletion = ((slider: LESKSliderNode, value: Float) -> ())
/**
Closure, which is executed when a touch begins
*/
var touchDown : LESKSliderNodeCompletion?
/**
Closure, which is executed when the thumb is dragged
*/
var touchMoved : LESKSliderNodeCompletion?
/**
Closure, which is executed when a touch ends
*/
var touchUp : LESKSliderNodeCompletion?
/**
Closure, which is executed when a touch ends inside the frame of the LESKSliderNode
*/
var touchUpInside : LESKSliderNodeCompletion?
/**
Closure, which is executed when a touch is cancelled
*/
var touchCancelled : LESKSliderNodeCompletion?


/**
Initializer
@param the string of the thumbSprite
@param the string of the scaleSprite
*/
convenience init(thumbString: String, scaleString: String)
{
    self.init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: thumbString), scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: scaleString), thumbSpriteActive: nil, scaleSpriteActive: nil)
}

/**
Initializer
@param the string of the thumbSprite
@param the string of the scaleSprite
@param the string of the thumbSpriteActive
@param the string of the scaleSpriteActive
*/
convenience init(thumbString: String, scaleString: String, thumbStringActive: String?, scaleStringActive: String?)
{
    self.init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: thumbString), scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: scaleString), thumbSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: thumbStringActive), scaleSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: scaleStringActive))
}


/**
Initializer
@param the texture of the thumbSprite
@param the texture of the scaleSprite
*/
convenience init(thumbTexture: SKTexture, scaleTexture: SKTexture)
{
    self.init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode(texture: thumbTexture), scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode(texture: scaleTexture), thumbSpriteActive: nil, scaleSpriteActive: nil)
}

/**
Initializer
@param the texture of the thumbSprite
@param the texture of the scaleSprite
@param the texture of the thumbSpriteActive
@param the texture of the scaleSpriteActive
*/
convenience init(thumbTexture: SKTexture, scaleTexture: SKTexture, thumbTextureActive: SKTexture?, scaleTextureActive: SKTexture?)
{
    self.init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode(texture: thumbTexture), scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode(texture: scaleTexture), thumbSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode(texture: thumbTextureActive), scaleSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode(texture: scaleTextureActive))
}

/**
Initializer
@param the sprite of the thumbSprite
@param the sprite of the scaleSprite
*/
convenience init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode, scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode)
{
    self.init(thumbSprite: thumbSprite, scaleSprite: scaleSprite)
}

/**
Initializer
@param the sprite of the thumbSprite
@param the sprite of the scaleSprite
@param the sprite of the thumbSpriteActive
@param the sprite of the scaleSpriteActive
*/
init(thumbSprite: SKSpriteNode, scaleSprite: SKSpriteNode, thumbSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode?, scaleSpriteActive: SKSpriteNode?)
{
    self.thumbSprite = thumbSprite
    self.scaleSprite = scaleSprite
    self.thumbSpriteActive = thumbSpriteActive
    self.scaleSpriteActive = scaleSpriteActive
    super.init()
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addChild(self.scaleSprite)
    self.addChild(self.thumbSprite)
    if self.scaleSpriteActive?
    {
        self.addChild(self.scaleSpriteActive)
        self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = true
    }
    if self.thumbSpriteActive?
    {
        self.addChild(self.thumbSpriteActive)
        self.thumbSpriteActive!.hidden = true
    }
    calculateNewThumbRange()
    self.size = scaleSprite.size
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if isEnabled
    {
        isActive = true
        if self.scaleSpriteActive?
        {
            self.scaleSprite.hidden = true
            self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = false
        }
        if self.thumbSpriteActive?
        {
            self.thumbSprite.hidden = true
            self.thumbSpriteActive!.hidden = false
        }
        moveThumbToValueAccordingToTouch(touches.anyObject() as UITouch)
        if touchDown? {touchDown!(slider: self, value: self.value)}
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if isEnabled
    {
        let touchPosition = (touches.anyObject() as UITouch).locationInNode(self.parent)
        if CGRectContainsPoint(self.frameInParent, touchPosition)
        {
            if self.scaleSpriteActive?
            {
                self.scaleSprite.hidden = true
                self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = false
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if self.scaleSpriteActive?
            {
                self.scaleSprite.hidden = false
                self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = true
            }
        }
        moveThumbToValueAccordingToTouch(touches.anyObject() as UITouch)
        if touchMoved? {touchMoved!(slider: self, value: self.value)}
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if isEnabled
    {
        isActive = false
        if self.scaleSpriteActive?
        {
            self.scaleSprite.hidden = false
            self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = true
        }
        if self.thumbSpriteActive?
        {
            self.thumbSprite.hidden = false
            self.thumbSpriteActive!.hidden = true
        }
        if touchUp? {touchUp!(slider: self, value: self.value)}
        let touchPosition = (touches.anyObject() as UITouch).locationInNode(self.parent)
        if CGRectContainsPoint(self.frameInParent, touchPosition) {if touchUpInside? {touchUpInside!(slider: self, value: self.value)}}
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if isEnabled
    {
        isActive = false
        if self.scaleSpriteActive?
        {
            self.scaleSprite.hidden = false
            self.scaleSpriteActive!.hidden = true
        }
        if self.thumbSpriteActive?
        {
            self.thumbSprite.hidden = false
            self.thumbSpriteActive!.hidden = true
        }
        if touchCancelled? {touchCancelled!(slider: self, value: self.value)}
    }
}

func moveThumbToValueAccordingToTouch(touch: UITouch)
{
    let touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var newPositionX = touchPosition.x
    if newPositionX < self.thumbRange.startIndex {newPositionX = self.thumbRange.startIndex}
    else if newPositionX > self.thumbRange.endIndex {newPositionX = self.thumbRange.endIndex}
    self.thumbSprite.position = CGPoint(x:newPositionX,y:self.thumbSprite.position.y)
    if self.thumbSpriteActive {self.thumbSpriteActive!.position = CGPoint(x:newPositionX,y:self.thumbSpriteActive!.position.y)}
}

func calculateNewThumbRange()
{
    self.thumbRange = (self.overlayThumb) ? Range(start: -scaleSprite.size.width/2, end: scaleSprite.size.width/2) : Range(start: -(scaleSprite.size.width / 2 - thumbSprite.size.width / 2), end: scaleSprite.size.width / 2 - thumbSprite.size.width / 2)
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really interesting and innovative solution; I'd love to play with it, though it does not compile in Xcode 6.0 (Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)). I tried to repair it for 6, but there are just too many errors.